# operator_enum of object.mesh_add and object.empty_add is displayed unexpected

Tags: python, scripting, interface

i'm writing an addon, that's simplifying the ui of blender dynamically for mesh-editing only purposes. So i want to simpify the add-menu of the 3d-view. But there i've the Problem, that if i uses this code

```
layout.operator_enum("object.mesh_add", "type") #new_line
layout.separator() #new_line
layout.operator_enum("object.empty_add", "type") #new_line
```

it looks like shown in this image:

[image]

I'm getting the same result if i'm writing an new menu-object or if i'm replacing code of the original menu-object. I'm using blender 2.76b of the ubuntu repositories (16.04).

Did i do something wrong or is this a bug i've to solve by a few of this lines:

```
layout.operator("object.<...>_add", icon='<...>', text="<...>").type = "<...>"
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution:

The API has been changed (Code from /usr/share/blender/scripts/startup/bl_ui/space_view3d.py):

```
class INFO_MT_mesh_add(Menu):
    bl_idname = "INFO_MT_mesh_add"
    bl_label = "Mesh"

    def draw(self, context):
        from .space_view3d_toolbar import VIEW3D_PT_tools_add_object

        layout = self.layout

        layout.operator_context = 'INVOKE_REGION_WIN'

        VIEW3D_PT_tools_add_object.draw_add_mesh(layout)
```

I was misleaded by this comment in INFO_MT_add:

```
#layout.operator_menu_enum("object.mesh_add", "type", text="Mesh", icon='OUTLINER_OB_MESH')
```

This code doesn't work anymore!